# How do I maintain my custom type during a RichTextBox copy paste?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a custom class derived from Hyperlink:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyHyperlink:Hyperlink
{   
    public MyHyperlink():base(){}
}
```

I add it to a `FlowDocument` inside of a `RichTextBox` and then serialize to xml with `XamlWriter.Save(thedoc)` resulting in the following, showing my custom type:

```
<FlowDocument PagePadding="5,0,5,0" AllowDrop="True" NumberSubstitution.CultureSource="User" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyAssembly;assembly=MyAssembly" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Paragraph>
        <local:MyHyperlink NavigateUri="//Omitted" IsEnabled="True">Juicy Link</local:MyHyperlink>
    </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

I run the app, Ctrl+X the RichTextBox content and Ctrl+V, and intercept the paste with my handler:

```
private void pastingHandler(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
{
    string raw = (string)data.GetData(DataFormats.Xaml);      
}
```

Inspecting the `raw` field, and it appears pasted content is pre-formatted inside of either a `System.Windows.Documents.Section` or a `System.Windows.Documents.Span`. However the end result always loses my type and is replaced with a `System.Windows.Documents.Hyperlink`, i.e. the base type.

How do I maintain my custom type when copying an/or pasting?

Edit: `Hyperlink` is not marked with the attribute [Serializable]. Therefore It cannot be serialized. However it might be possible with `ISerializationSurrogate`. I will report back.